# Fixed thread pool with a size of one and making it sequenctial <- Are they same?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);  // Size of one
```

When I sequentially (in a for loop) do my jobs it takes approximately takes 2 seconds. 
And when I made the jobs done by es it also takes approximately 2 seconds.

I am not a benchmark expert.

**But can I safely say that the jobs takes x amount of time sequentially after changing thread pool size to one ?**

Comment: Which thread you use to do the tasks doesn't matter.  The only thing which might matter is that a loop has lower overhead.  Try doing ten million empty tasks each way and you will see a difference.

Comment: I am using thread sleep for 1ms simulating the job overhead.For 100000  with tp with size of 1 : 105055 ms and sequentially it is 104280ms . (Further going into this makes it premature I guess)

Comment: If your tasks take 1 ms you are unlikely to see a consistent difference (across machines/JVMs) if you have a 1 micro-second tasks, then you will see a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one thread in that thread pool. The thread will take a `Runnable` or `Callable` task that has been submit and execute it. When it is done, the same thread will pick up and execute the next task. And so on. It is more or less equivalent to executing the tasks sequentially.

Comment: My guts also told me like this but have you come across such a standard or a trustworthy document saying this ?

Comment: @cgon The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) and the source code itself. `If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available. `

Comment: @cgon, how could it _not_ be sequential?  There is only one thread in the pool, and one thread can only do one thing at a time.